# which is the best algorithm to to find a image which is similar to the "input" image from a set of images

Tags: android, algorithm, image-processing

I'm developing an android app for tourists. I need to display information about heritage buildings. I have to compare the photos taken by the tourist with my own database to check if I'm having the info related to that building.since photo taken by tourist may not be exactly same as the photo in my database so I'm looking for an algorithm to find similar images in real time. I have read about algorithms like SURF, SIFT, pHash but still i am confused about which to use.(Image comparison will be done at the server side and not by the application.)

Comment: Your question, for real time scenarios, is still a matter of research. I think you should read about `bag of words`, which is the image similarity measure in use. (it is also used by google in its image search, along with a lot of improvisations, of course).

Comment: Also, you **will** have to use AI (machine learning) by taking reviews from users (if you are serious about the functionality of your app).

Comment: And no single, simple algorithm can even give you ~60% correct results if images are not **exactly** same, which will not be the case. Brightness, gradation, angle, perspective, distance, lens, day/night-light and 143 other features are there, which are actually impossible to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Use an image hashing algorithm.

- Hash all your stored images
- Hash your incoming image
- Compare your incoming image' hash to your stored hashes.

For a simple image hash:

- Resize your image to a small standard size (like 16x16) so the hash doesn't take up too much space
- Convert your image to gray scale
- If a pixel value is greater than the average grayscale value, set it to 1 else set it to 0

Here's some code that hashes an already resized image

```
​function imageHash(pixels) {
  var result = [],
    sum = 0,
    size = pixels.length,
    gray, r, g, b, c, avg, i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    r = (pixels[i] >> 16) & 0xFF;
    g = (pixels[i] >> 8) & 0xFF;
    b = (pixels[i]) & 0xFF;
    gray = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b;
    sum += gray;
    result[i] = gray;
  }
  avg = sum / size;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    result[i] = result[i] > avg ? 1 : 0;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: will it give same result for photos having different brightness. and thanks for the solution.

Comment: @US_Thakur - since the hash uses the average brightness as the threshold for a binary result (1 or 0) then as long as the image is brightened in a unfirom way it should work. When comparing the hashes you can sum the number of matched bits and use that as a score for 'how similar' the two are.